# How to enlarge Minecraft debug pie chart on my desktop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using my pie chart to locate a spawner, but the texts displayed below it were too small to read that they were basically pixels.

I'm therefore finding any method to enlarge that pie chart as well as the texts below so that I can read them normally.

Comment: How do you use the pie chart to locate a lawner? Entity count?

Comment: @Ray Wu: I was using it to find mobspawner, but the letters displayed were too small to read, which undoubtedly caused difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was to make Minecraft smaller by using the box next to the close and minimize button. This makes the pie chart much bigger, but it's kind of painful to look at.